# Get calculated values with cumulative rate/percentage applied

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that contains value amounts. I have another table that needs to apply a rate to those value amounts, but the complicated part is that it needs to be calculated cumulatively. Consider I have an amount of 8500 coming from my first table, and here are my rates:

```
AmtFrom     AmtTo       Rate
0.00        2500.00     0.1
2500.01     5000.00     0.2
5000.01     10000.00    0.3
100000.01   20000.00    0.4
```

I need to be able to return three rows here, with the rate being calculated on each range. This would be the expected result for my 8500 amount:

```
Amount      Rate    Calculated
2500.00     0.1     250.00
2500.00     0.2     500.00
3500.00     0.3     1050.00
```

As you can see, the Amount column sum would be 8500, but the rate is applied to each range individually.

My best guess to deal with this would be some sort of recursive CTE, which I've done before with implementations of a recursive search through parent/child relationships, but I'm at a complete loss of how to do it here, or if that's even the best solution...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a recursive CTE, just some arithmetic logic:

```
select (case when t.amount >= r.AmountTo then r.AmountTo - r.AmountFrom
             else t.amount - r.AmountFrom
        end) as Amount,
       r.rate,
       (case when t.amount >= r.AmountTo then r.AmountTo - r.AmountFrom
             else t.amount - r.AmountFrom
        end) * r.rate as Calculated
from (select 8500 as amount) t join
     rates r
     on r.AmountFrom <= t.amount;
```

Your explanation is a bit vague about what to do about the 0.01 offset for the `rates.AmountFrom` column.  I suspect you will want to add this back `then` clauses of the `case` statement.

Comment: The offset is irrelevant. I just used rounder amounts for ease of reading. Thank you for this answer; I guess this is one of those cases of SEVERELY over-thinking the problem when a simple solution is staring me in the face.